# Debo sumar las posiciones de un arreglo, la primera con la segunda y el resultado sumarlo con la siguiente

Tags: java, array, matrices

Quiero sumar las posiciones de una lista de la siguiente manera:

`lista {1,3,4,5}-> 1 + 3 = 4 ; 4 + 4 = 8 ; 8 + 5 = 13`

Cada suma debe guardarse en otra lista o intercambiar la posición

`listaResultado {1,4,8,13}`

Intenté esto en java, pero solo funciona cuando n(numero), está ordenado de menor a mayor.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Persona p[] = new Persona[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("N: ")); //atributo de persona que necesito sumar
        String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("M: ");//atributo nombre Persona
        p[i] = new Persona(n,m); //Arreglo de objetos 

        //Clase Persona tiene 2 atributos, numero (la lista que debo sumar) y nombre
    }
        
    int v[] = new int [p.length];
    int suma[] = new int [p.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        v[i] = p[i].getNumero();
        System.out.println(""+v[i]);
    }
        
    suma[0] = v[0];
        
    for (int i = 1; i < suma.length; i++) {
        suma[i] =v[i]+v[i-1];
    }
        
    for (int i = 0; i < suma.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\n\n-----------"+suma[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int suma = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < vectorOriginal.length; i++)
{
   suma += vectorOriginal[i];
   vectorSuma[i] = suma;
}
```

Tienes dos arreglos **vectorOriginal** que guarda los números que serán sumados y **vectorSuma** que guarda cada suma hecha sobre los elementos de **vectorOriginal**.

Omito las declaraciones de estos arreglos ya que me concentro solamente en la suma que pides y como guardar cada suma.

Se declara la **variable suma** y se inicializa en 0, está variable es la que nos permitirá hacer la sumatoria de los elementos de **vectorOriginal** e ir guardando cada suma en **vectorSuma**.

Posteriormente hago un **ciclo for** que irá recorriendo cada posición de **vectorOriginal** e irá sumando cada elemento con el valor que ya existe en la **variable suma**, cada valor obtenido en la **variable suma** se guardará en la posición indicada en **vectorSuma** .